# SDL2 Mass Rendering of Textures faster than rendering across different loops?

Tags: c++, sdl-2

I'm making a game in SDL2, and I have a glow image that's rendered behind bullets and particles. The unoptimized version renders the glow image in the bullets iterations and particle iterations. The optimized version simply renders the glow image all at once (at the recorded glow locations). This is kind of strange, and I'd like to know of any other solutions than mass rendering the glow image (it looks strange since it's not rendered at the correct point in the game loop). This is an example of the unoptimized version:

```cpp
for (Particle &particle: particles){
    if (particle.update(renderer)){
        new_particles.push_back(particle);
        
        // glow
        glow_rect.x = particle.x;
        glow_rect.y = particle.y;
        glow_rect.w = particle.width * 2;
        glow_rect.h = particle.height * 2;
        SDL_SetTextureAlphaMod(glow_vignette, particle.alpha);
        centerRect(glow_rect);
        camera.renderCopy(renderer, glow_vignette, NULL, &glow_rect);
    }
}
```

whereas in the optimized version (rendering all glows at once):

```
// show glows
for (auto [rect, alpha]: glow_locs){
    SDL_SetTextureAlphaMod(glow_vignette, alpha);
    camera.renderCopy(renderer, glow_vignette, NULL, &rect);
}
```

Comment: Not sure what your question is, could you clarify that? Is your problem appears on overlapping particles?

Comment: @keltar i actually solved it by rendering stuff all together in a separate piece of code... although the problem was that rendering a texture in different loops was slower than mass rendering it in one loop.

Comment: Switching textures is slow from the early days of accelerated graphics. SDL could batch all your rectangles to single draw if no rendering state changes between them; graphics driver could do that as well.

Comment: @keltar is the lag because i'm using accelerated graphics?

Comment: removing accelerated graphics and rendering them across different loops is still as laggy.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by lag. If you have bad performance, switching to software rendering most likely will give you even worse performance. What you have is an example of benefits of "graphics batching" (should be google-able term). You can render a lot of polygons with the same render state, but if you switch state for each polygon - your performance will be dramatically lower. If you absolutely have to have specific draw order (e.g. because of blending) then your options are quite limited.

Comment: is not having a specific draw order in games a bad idea?